# "Can't find variable: window" in suds.js

Tags: javascript, soap, titanium-mobile, suds

I am trying to test out receiving SOAP responses in a mobile app I am building in Titanium Studio (version 2.1.1). I am using the suds library to do so, but when I do the call for it, I get the error

`[WARN] Exception in event callback. {

    line = 27;

    message = "Can't find variable: window"`

I am not really sure why I am getting this, I have the suds.js library included and the app doesn't crash, it just won't send. The code I am using to implement this is:

```
var suds = new SudsClient({ 
  endpoint: 'http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL',
  targetNamespace: 'http://ws.cdyne.com/' 
    });


    var soapBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title:'SOAP',
        bottom:'100'
    });
    homeHolder.add(soapBtn);

    var callParams = {
    ZIP:'33325'
    };

    soapBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){

    suds.invoke("GetCityForecastByZIP", callParams, function(xmlDoc) {
        var response = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('GetCityForecastByZIPResult');
        Ti.API.info(response);
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It's referencing the suds.js file, which is the first time the reference to window @line 27 exists. It's a reserved word so I'm not sure why it is giving this error.

Comment: window is not available in Titanium. Only in webview

Comment: Have you looked at their titanium mobile example?

Comment: I have but it was written for 0.7 and doesn't seem to compile properly.

Comment: You need to post the calling code and the rest of this code as well.  This code doesn't mention window, so the error doesn't make sense.  For example, what is homeHolder?  Is it a view, is it a window, is it a tablerowview?  All you are going to get is guesses at best.  Show us the main window definition file as well as this entire file.  I suspect the reason it isn't sending is because your program hit an error before ever hitting this code and it stopped.  This doesn't necessarily halt all app execution all the time.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this error because you are not using the modified suds.js for titanium, you can get the correct one either from the kitchen sink example or from the titanium mobile example on the suds github 
https://github.com/kwhinnery/Suds/tree/master/TitaniumMobileExample/CurrencyConverter/Resources

Comment: The suds.js in the github won't solve the problem. Tried it ....but getting the same error.

The suds.js in the latest KitchenSink example addresses this issue and is working fine... :-)